# Injecting JS into a WebView before sending any page activity

Tags: android, webview, service-worker

I want to intercept POST requests from a custom page, which is impossible from the callback client interface (unlike to GET one, you have no access to the POST request body). So, I have implemented a service worker based solution, which wrapping POST request into a GET one with the same data, that I can handle in shouldInterceptRequest().

So, once the service worker is registered and active:

```
function subscribeToSWMessages()
{
    navigator.serviceWorker.onmessage = function (event)
    {
        if (event.data.command == 'activeSW')
        {
                // !! Only from now we can post requests !!
        }
    };
}
```

Only after that it's safe to post request from the page. So, how to properly inject my JS code, to be sure no requests are posted until the message is received? Can the page be totally custom, or I should ask its developer to do something on their side?